# Jhipster Gateway - Blank page

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I'm using jhipster version 4.14.4 to generate jhispter gateway.
Everything is working fine in local.

I using below command to compile war file as usual use for "Monolithic application".

```
"Mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests"
```

It showing blank page when deployed to server. Registry/microservices/gateway are started without any errors. But Gateway page in browser F12 console got errors as below:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) global.7f47cf62bb4699a8e4e2.bundle.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) vendor.7f47cf62bb4699a8e4e2.bundle.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) manifest.7f47cf62bb4699a8e4e2.bundle.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) polyfills.7f47cf62bb4699a8e4e2.bundle.js:1
```

However, the global/vendor/manifest/polyfills files are exist inside war file "app" folder.

I did try

1. deploy a totally new generated gateway without any changes in server.
2. browser clear cache and redeploy.
3. delete node_modules and npm install again.
4. clean package, and compile war file

Still having the same issue.

Comment: A prod build does not use the node_modules directory from your project nor the node/npm you installed globally, frontend-maven-plugin installs its own node/npm in a node sub folder of your project and it includes also its own node_modules. So, if you want to clean it up, you should delete node folder. Also 4.14.4 is 3 years old, so I suspect it's not the first time you run a build prod, what has changed since last success?

Comment: ok, i will delete node folder and try again. I'm new in microservice/gateway. Before that i only use the Monolithic application. As i mention, i did try deploy a totally new generated gateway without any changes in server. But still getting the same errors.

Comment: Deleted the node folder, npm install, clean package and compile again. Still getting the same errors when deployed to server.

Comment: If you are starting with microservice/gateway, why do you use JHipster 4? Generate your new apps with JHipster 7.1. You can still use JHipster 4 in your monolith as JHipster copies itself locally in each project, so working with different versions is supported and it makes complete sense in a microservice architecture as you would not want to develop new apps with spring boot 1.5

Comment: ok, i will try the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "mvnw package -Pprod,webpack -DskipTests"?